# Using Firerstore Timestamp in datetime-local Input

Tags: javascript, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting a timestamp from Firestore and trying to have it populate a datetime input field. I'm using moment.js to format my date.

```
<input id="time" type="datetime-local" placeholder="Event date/time">
```

JS

```
var time = docData.time.toDate();
console.log(time);
var formattedDate = moment(time).format('yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm');
console.log(formattedDate);
document.getElementById("time").value = formattedDate.toLocaleString();
```

Result of logging the 'time' var

```
Wed Nov 28 2018 14:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Result of logging 'formattedDate'

```
yyyy-11-28 02:00
```

Warning message in console.

```
events.js:85 The specified value "yyyy-11-28 02:00" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with this.

```
var formattedDate = moment(time).format("YYYY-MM-DDTkk:mm");
```